# Remove duplicate rows in a text file

Tags: file-io, fortran

How do I remove duplicate rows of string while reading a .txt file using Fortran?
This is my code currently and I'm headed on a really wrong path. Currently, I'm trying to hold the first line constant for example and then comparing it to the lines after it.

```
PROGRAM REM_DUP
IMPLICIT NONE
CHARACTER(632) :: ROW3, ROW4
INTEGER :: I

OPEN(UNIT=23, FILE="APM_FORMATTED.TXT", ACTION="READ", STATUS="OLD")
OPEN(UNIT=25, FILE="APM_DUPLICATES.TXT", ACTION="WRITE", STATUS="NEW")

DO
READ(23,'(A632)', END=199) ROW3
I=1
OPEN(UNIT=24, FILE="APM_FORMATTED1.TXT", ACTION="READWRITE", ACCESS="APPEND", STATUS="OLD")
    DO
    READ(24,'(A632)', END=299) ROW4
        IF(ROW3(33:52).EQ.ROW4(33:52)) THEN
        I=I+1
            IF (I.GE.3) THEN
            WRITE(25,'(A632)') ROW3
            ENDIF
        ELSE 
        WRITE(24, '(A632)') ROW3
        ENDIF
    ENDDO
    CLOSE(24)
ENDDO
```

199 CLOSE(23)
299 CLOSE(24)
    CLOSE(25)

```
END PROGRAM REM_DUP
```

Comment: Depending on file size, `Ctrl+k` in a text editor might be faster...

Comment: Its a large file size. This is also a part of a bigger code so including the duplicate-removal functionality will be ideal.

Comment: Does it have to be done in fortran? If you are in a unix environment, the utilities `sort` and `uniq` can achieve this very quickly.

Comment: is every input line exactly 632 characters? If not you are blank padding each line out to 632..  you can use write(unit,'(a)')trim(out), but then you loose any existing blank padding as well.

Comment: @Yossarian note he's checking only on a substring, so sort wont do (unless the substring can be pulled out by --key )

Comment: @george Good point. I think `--key` should be able to extract any substring, provided you know the format beforehand (which it seems like OP does). Fortran isn't really the right tool for text manipulation - better to use something more suited, like `awk`.

Comment: Each line is indeed 632 characters. I just updated the code again. It makes sense to me in terms of tracing but no idea why its not entering the 2nd DO loop. Also, yes I have only a windows machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following might be horrendously slow, but it should work.

```
i=1
READ(23,'(A632)') row3
WRITE(24,'(A632)') row3 ! assume first read was unique (pretty good assumption)
DO
   READ(23,'(A632)',IOSTAT=ierr) row3
! a successful read returns ierr=0; end-of-file returns -1
   IF(ierr/=0) EXIT
! make sure we are reading from the top of the file
   REWIND(24)
   flag=.false.
! loop through file 24 for comparing
   DO k=1,i
      READ(24,'(A632)') row4
! if the line is repeated, write row3 to bad file (?) & set flag as true
      IF(row3(33:52)==row4(33:52)) THEN
         WRITE(25,'(A632)') row3
         flag = .true.
      ENDIF
   ENDDO
! if row3 is not repeated it, add to file 24 & increment i
   IF(.not.flag) THEN
      WRITE(24,'(A632)') row3
      i=i+1
   ENDIF
ENDDO
CLOSE(24); CLOSE(23); CLOSE(25)
```

Hopefully the comments are enough to understand.

Comment: sorry, but rewinding and rereading the entire file for each line, really??

Comment: Does someone else any recommendations? Sorry but the code is taking too long to run since my original file is 100MB+. It stops quarter of the way (guessing because of memory problems but not entirely sure).

Comment: 100MB is not big. Read the entire file storing the sort key as an array character*20 (maxlines), sort the key field array, then go back and process the file. However, make sure you understand my note above about blank padding before wasting any more time trying to do this in fortran.

Comment: @george: (a) the OP's idea was to compare each line to **every** previous line and (b) I explicitly stated that this was probably a horrendously slow solution.

Comment: Surprisingly, I just found out that I can only use F77 so REWIND() is not an option.

Comment: @KyleKanos You have a brilliant solution which I am not able to replicate(my code stops at line 2 for some reason). Time is not an issue but your code seems to stop working at line 13125 for some reason. Hope you can help me understand why. Thanks!

Comment: if you must do f77 (homework?) you have a dozen problems. rewind is not one of them

Comment: @user1436056: if there is no `rewind`, then I think that the only option would be to `close` & re-`open` each iteration.